# Remove or move the button banner of autoformat

Tags: microsoft-word

How do I get rid of this annoying button that is hovering over words:

[image]

Comment: [Undo or turn off automatic formatting](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Undo-or-turn-off-automatic-formatting-195c72fc-5e3f-43d5-a0c3-bf3606e2e58e?CTT=1&CorrelationId=125e82bb-2b00-4343-a3ce-5c372da859ce&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Answer (score 2):

If you still want to use Automatic Formatting and just want to disable the button, you can do so in Word's AutoCorrect Options.

1. When the AutoCorrect button appears, click it and select **Control AutoFormat Options...**

   [image: AutoCorrect Mini Menu in Word 2007]
2. Click the **AutoCorrect** tab and clear the checkbox for **Show AutoCorrect Options buttons**.

   [image: Disable AutoCorrect Options buttons]

<sub>(Verified on Word 2007 and Word 2010 on Windows 7)</sub>